# Unselect MUI Multi select with initial value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, multi-select

I got a problem with MUI Select (multiple) inside a Formik form.
Suppose that I have a task stored in database with `taskName`, `assignTo` (array of staff).
Now I'm trying to make a form where I can update/change `assignTo` values.
So the form got `initialValues` with:

```
const savedTask = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Task A",
  assignTo: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Oliver Hansen",
      age: 32
    }
  ]
};
```

and people list

```
const personList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Oliver Hansen",
    age: 32
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Van Henry",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Oliver",
    age: 27
  }
];
```

The problem is I can't unselect "Oliver Hansen" in the update form. When I click on it, it also adds one more "Oliver Hansen".

[image]

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-hellman-mc16j?fbclid=IwAR1MvDl_zOvrEwdMb0rv74Op6Mhg5oJr5RBCQPOG7hP7QkUBcfyoxc2jM_I&file=/src/App.js)

Did I implement wrong or that's how formik `setFieldValues` behaves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Select API page(`value` prop)](https://mui.com/api/select/#props):

> ...
>
> If the value is an object it must have reference equality with the
> option in order to be selected. If the value is not an object, the
> string representation must match with the string representation of the
> option in order to be selected.

`savedTask.assignTo` and `personList` have different object references even if they have the same value, so you have to use `Array.filter` to have the initial value of  `assignTo` from `personList` like this:

```
const initValues = { 
  ...savedTask, 
  assignTo: personList.filter(person => savedTask.assignTo.some(obj => obj.id === person.id))
};

const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: initValues,
  onSubmit: (values) => {
    console.log("values submit ", values);
  }
});
```

Working example:

[image: Edit hopeful-johnson-q75g8]

Comment: I know they have different object references but didn't think how to modify initialValues. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to set the initial value of your state to reset it. In my case I have a list and set the value to my placeholder.

```
const [yearFrame, setYearFrame] = React.useState<string[]>([newDate]);
const handleYearFrame = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof yearFrame>) => {
        const { target: { value }, } = event;
        if (value === yearFrame[0]) {
            setYearFrame(["Select Year"]);
        }
        else {
            setYearFrame(
                typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value
            );
        }
    };
```

In the textfield:

```
<FormControl style={{ width: "30vh", marginLeft: "2vh", marginTop: "2vh" }}>
  <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">Select Year</InputLabel>
    <Select
      value={yearFrame}
      onChange={handleYearFrame}
      input={<OutlinedInput label="Select Year" />}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
    >
      {optionsYear.map((option) => {
        return (option.label === "Select Year" ? <MenuItem key= 
          {option.label} disabled value={option.label}><span style={{ color: 
          "rgb(156, 156, 156)" }}>{option.label}</span></MenuItem> : 
          <MenuItem key={option.label} value={option.label}>{option.label} 
           </MenuItem>)
         })}
   </Select>
</FormControl>
```

This is because I am reusing logic and have the same textfield as a multi-select so the value appears as a list. If you are not using a multi-select you can set the state to null and it will automatically render your placeholder.